# Unable to connect to the Report Server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Win/7 Professional
SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Reporting Services Configuration Manager

When I launch it, shows correct Server Name, but report server instance is blank. When I press FIND I get:

"Unable to connect to the Report Server "

This is my development workstation, so no IIS installed. Seems to work fine on XP. SSMS works fine - no issues.

I tried uninstalling SQL Server completely, rebooting, reinstalling a fresh download. Same result. I've googled every article I can find - nothing.

I know this is programming forum, but can anyone point me in the right direction in case you've come across this yourself? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't download the correct edition.  It has to be the one with advanced services under "other installation options".  This also installs a copy of VS 2008 with the report project (BI) templates.

The problem is that the non-advanced version still installs the Reporting Services Configuration Manager, giving you the impression you have the right software, it just doesn't work and none of the error messages are obvious.
[Link to other install options here.](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/InstallOptions.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured SQL Server to allow remote connections?

[How to configure SQL Server 2005 to allow remote connections](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;914277) (applies to 2008 as well)